# Multiple definition of first defined here with only one file

Tags: c

I'm really new to c and I'm having an error when I compile my code with -g.
When i compile my code with -o, it compiles but crashes.
When I compile with -g, these are the error messages:

```
/afs/pitt.edu/home/j/t/jth64/private/cs449/proj1test/bmp_edit.c:42: multiple 
definition of `invert'
proj1test:(.text+0xe4): first defined here
/tmp/ccA3Apso.o: In function `main':
/afs/pitt.edu/home/j/t/jth64/private/cs449/proj1test/bmp_edit.c:110: 
 multiple definition of `main'
proj1test:(.text+0x4b7): first defined here
```

There's more text, but I'm pretty sure these two are the only problem. I read up a lot about this before I posted this problem, but it seems like all of the other linker errors are because of multiple files, while I'm getting them and I only have one file.

Here is the file I have currently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct headBMP {
    char formatIdentifier[2];
    int fileSize;
    short resVal1;
    short resVal2;
    int offSet;
};

struct headDIB {
    int headerSize;
    int width;
    int height;
    short planes;
    short bitsPerPixel;
    int compressionScheme;
    int imageSize;
    int horizontalRes;
    int verticalRes;
    int palette;
    int importantColors;
};

struct headRGB {
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
};

void invert (char file[])
{
    struct headBMP bmp;
    struct headDIB dib;
    struct headRGB rgb;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (file, "rb+");
    /*--------BMP--------*/
    fread (bmp.formatIdentifier, 1, 2, fp);
    if (bmp.formatIdentifier[0] != 'B' || bmp.formatIdentifier[1] != 'M') {
        printf ("We do not support this type of file! \n");
        exit (-1);
    }
    fread (&bmp.fileSize, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&bmp.resVal1, 2, 1, fp);
    fread (&bmp.resVal2, 2, 1, fp);
    fread (&bmp.offSet, 4, 1, fp);

    /*--------DIB--------*/
    fread (&dib.headerSize, 4, 1, fp);
    if (dib.headerSize != 40) {
        printf ("We do not support this type of file! \n");
        exit (-1);
    }
    fread (&dib.width, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.height, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.planes, 2, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.bitsPerPixel, 2, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.compressionScheme, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.imageSize, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.horizontalRes, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.verticalRes, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.palette, 4, 1, fp);
    fread (&dib.importantColors, 4, 1, fp);
    /*fseek(fp, 10, SEEK_SET);*/

    /*--------RGB--------*/
    int i = 0;
    while (i < dib.width) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < dib.height) {
            fread (&rgb.red, 1, 1, fp);
            unsigned int r = rgb.red;
            r = ~r;
            rgb.red = (char) r;

            fread (&rgb.green, 1, 1, fp);
            unsigned int g = rgb.green;
            g = ~g;
            rgb.green = (char) g;

            fread (&rgb.blue, 1, 1, fp);
            unsigned int b = rgb.blue;
            b = ~b;
            rgb.blue = (char) b;

            fseek (fp, -3, SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite (&rgb.red, 1, 1, fp);
            fwrite (&rgb.green, 1, 1, fp);
            fwrite (&rgb.blue, 1, 1, fp);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose (fp);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (strncmp (argv[1], "-invert", 7) == 0) {
        invert (argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This has been weighing on my mind a lot, so I appreciate any help. Cheers.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling? Please post the full command.

Comment: You fix that warning with `if (argc < 2) { fprintf (stderr, "error: filename required.\n"); return 1; }`

Comment: I apologize, that was a copy/paste error. My bad. Your code compiles fine aside from the warning. E.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/bmp_edit bmp_edit.c`  **Also** you may want to check your file for non-ASCII characters that are causing problems like a Byte-Order-Mark at the beginning or stray utf-8 symbols.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]`  without first checking `argc` to assure the desired command line parameter was actually entered by the user.

Comment: the posted code contains MANY calls to `fread()`.  Any/all of those calls could fail.  I.E. Always check the returned value against the third parameter to assure the operation was successful.  Note: I/O is orders of magnitude slower than memory.  Suggest reading the whole pixel map in one call to `fread()`, then perform all the manipulation of the values, then write all the pixel map back to the file in a single call to `fwrite()`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code is making the assumption that the number of bits per pixel is 24. This is (often/usually) not a valid assumption. The number of bits could be 8 or 16 or 24 or 32.

Comment: in a .bmp file, the number of bytes in a row has to be a multiple of 4. This means there may be some 'filler' bytes at the end of each row. The code needs to allow for that detail.

Comment: regarding: `invert (argv[1]);`  since `argv[1]` contains `-invert`, it must be `argv[2]` that contains the name of the .bmp file to manipulate. Suggest: `invert( argv[2] );`

Comment: the offset to the beginning of the pixel table can vary quite a lot,  so use the field "File Offset to Pixel Array' (which is at a 10 byte offset into the file) to locate the pixel array.

Comment: use the field: Image Width` and the field: `Bits Per Pixel` to calculate if any padding is used in each row of the pixel data

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, you have just messed up the `argv[X]` indexing in `main()`. What you need is:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n"
                        "usage: %s [-invert] <filename.bmp>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    if (strncmp (argv[1], "-invert", 7) == 0) {
        invert (argv[2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** the change of `invert (argv[1])` to `invert (argv[2])`...

I would also recopy your code from the listing above to insure you do not have any stray non-ASCII characters causing your problems. Remember, code must be plain-text. You cannot edit it in any editor that will store binary formatting characters in your source file. You also need to check to make sure you don't include a BOM (byte-order-mark) as the first three characters of the file (although some compilers will ignore it).

The easiest way to check to see if you have additional characters in your code is with `hexdump -Cv yourfile` (on Linux) or opening your file in WinHex (or equivalent) on windoze. You may also want to run your code through `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` (as required) to make sure line-ending, etc are not causing you problems.

**Compile:**

With the addition of the `argc` check and fixing your indexing, your code compiles without warning:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/bmp_edit bmp_edit.c
```

(and yes, it does invert the bitmap)

[image]

Then running your code:

```
./bin/bmp_edit -invert ~/tmp/tt/testbmp_black.bmp
```

And the resulting `.bmp`

[image]

---

**Update Per-Comment, Re-Validation**

Before looking at how you should completely validate your `fopen`, `fread` and `fwrite`, a note about C style. While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)

Now on to **Validation**. C does not protect you from doing something stupid. It does exactly what you tell it to do and it comes without training-wheels. Meaning if you call `fopen` on a file that doesn't exist and then start using the `FILE*` pointer in calls to `fread`, etc.., C doesn't issue the error (`"File Not Found"`) for you -- that is up to you to include in your code.

The rules for validation are simple. If you open it, validate it's open. If you read from it, validate you read what you intended. If you write to it, validate your wrote what you think you write. If you close it after a write, validate there were no errors on close. If you allocate it, validate the allocation succeeded, etc... you get the drift. ***Validate, validate, validate!!***.

Re-writing your code with sufficient validation to determine where any failure occurs -- at any point during the open, read or write process isn't difficult (albeit a bit tedious). Simply follow the rules:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct headbmp {
    int filesize,
        offset;
    short resval1,
        resval2;
    char formatidentifier[2];
};

struct headdib {
    int headersize,
        width,
        height,
        compressionscheme,
        imagesize,
        horizontalres,
        verticalres,
        palette,
        importantcolors;
    short planes,
        bitsperpixel;
};

struct headrgb {
    unsigned char red, blue, green;
};

void invert (char *file)
{
    struct headbmp bmp;
    struct headdib dib;
    struct headrgb rgb;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen (file, "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen - file");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*--------bmp--------*/
    if (fread (bmp.formatidentifier, 1, 2, fp) != 2) {
        perror ("fread - bmp.formatidentifier");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (bmp.formatidentifier[0] != 'B' || bmp.formatidentifier[1] != 'M') {
        printf ("we do not support this type of file! \n");
        exit (-1);
    }
    if (fread (&bmp.filesize, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - bmp.filesize");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&bmp.resval1, 1, 2, fp) != 2) {
        perror ("fread - bmp.resval1");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&bmp.resval2, 1, 2, fp) != 2) {
        perror ("fread - bmp.resval2");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&bmp.offset, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - bmp.offset");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*--------dib--------*/
    if (fread (&dib.headersize, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.headersize");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (dib.headersize != 40) {
        printf ("we do not support this type of file! \n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.width, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.width");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.height, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.height");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.planes, 1, 2, fp) != 2) {
        perror ("fread - dib.planes");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.bitsperpixel, 1, 2, fp) != 2) {
        perror ("fread - dib.bitsperpixel");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.compressionscheme, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.compressionscheme");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.imagesize, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.imagesize");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.horizontalres, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.horizontalres");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.verticalres, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.verticalres");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.palette, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.palette");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fread (&dib.importantcolors, 1, 4, fp) != 4) {
        perror ("fread - dib.importantcolors");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*--------rgb--------*/
    int i = 0;
    while (i < dib.width) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < dib.height) {
            if (!fread (&rgb.red, 1, 1, fp)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: fread - red (%d,%d)\n", i, j);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            unsigned int r = rgb.red;
            r = ~r;
            rgb.red = (char) r;

            if (!fread (&rgb.green, 1, 1, fp)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: fread - green (%d,%d)\n", i, j);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            unsigned int g = rgb.green;
            g = ~g;
            rgb.green = (char) g;

            if (!fread (&rgb.blue, 1, 1, fp)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: fread - blue (%d,%d)\n", i, j);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            unsigned int b = rgb.blue;
            b = ~b;
            rgb.blue = (char) b;

            if (fseek (fp, -3, SEEK_CUR) == -1) {
                perror ("fseek -3");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (!fwrite (&rgb.red, 1, 1, fp)) {
                perror ("fwrite - red");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (!fwrite (&rgb.green, 1, 1, fp)) {
                perror ("fwrite - green");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (!fwrite (&rgb.blue, 1, 1, fp)) {
                perror ("fwrite - blue");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (fclose (fp) == -1)
        perror ("fclose - fp");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n"
                        "usage: %s -invert <filename.bmp>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    if (strncmp (argv[1], "-invert", 7) == 0) {
        invert (argv[2]);
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: unrecognized option.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Look things over and make sure you understand the validations. If you don't, just ask.

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate your solution! I am, however, still running into problems. For some reason, I still get a segmentation fault when I try to run my code. Here's what i type when I try to run it:

   " ./proj1test -invert change.bmp ".

My change.bmp is located on my desktop. Is that the reason my program keeps crashing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JHan - the biggest problems I see is you do not validate your `fopen` or `fread` or `fwrire`. You should check after `fopen` with `if (fp == NULL) { perror ("fopen file"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }`. Similarly, you should check each `fread` (and I would switch your `size` and `nmemb` parameters so `size` is always `1` so you always return the number of bytes), e.g. `if (fread (&dib.headerSize, 1, 4, fp) != 4) { perror ("fread - headerSize"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }`. (the same for `fwrite`) Then you will find where your program is failing.

Comment: @JHan -- and yes, you need to give your program the complete PATH to your bitmap (e.g. `/home/youruser/Desktop/change.bmp` or if using bash a simple `~/Desktop/change.bmp` will do) -- the SegFault is the result of you failing to validate your file is open before trying to read from it `:)`